Issue with Record Visibility After Insert in Custom PostgreSQL C Function Using SPI
I’m reaching out to seek advice regarding an issue I’ve encountered while working with PostgreSQL’s SPI (Server Programming Interface) in a custom C function. The core problem is that after performing an insert operation via SPI, a subsequent select query in the same function is not able to see the inserted row. Below, I’ll outline the problem, along with some details of my implementation and the debugging steps I’ve already attempted.
Problem Overview
In my custom C function, I’m inserting a new document into a table, followed immediately by a select query to fetch the same document for validation. The function is structured to perform these operations using SPI. However, the select query does not seem to find the document that was just inserted, and it returns no results.
Here’s a simplified version of the function:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.command_insert_and_read(p_request_body bytea)
RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE c
 VOLATILE STRICT
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', $function$command_insert_and_read$function$;

Datum command_insert_and_read(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
   ….. Some processing to extract the details of document to be inserted from the function args …..
    // Insert a new record into the table
    const char *upsertQuery = psprintf(
        "INSERT INTO database.table (document, id, partition_key) "
        "VALUES (to_jsonb($1), '1234', 7598981674407438314) RETURNING document");

    Datum args[1] = { resourceBodyDatum };
    Oid argTypes[1] = { TEXTOID };

    bool isNull[1];
    Datum returnValues[1] = { 0 };
    int expectedSPIOKs[2] = { SPI_OK_UPDATE_RETURNING, SPI_OK_INSERT_RETURNING };

    if (SPI_connect() != SPI_OK_CONNECT)
        ereport(ERROR, (errmsg("could not connect to SPI manager")));

    int res = SPI_execute_with_args(upsertQuery, 1, argTypes, args, NULL, false, 1);

    if (res != expectedSPIOKs[0] && res != expectedSPIOKs[1])
        ereport(ERROR, (errmsg("Unexpected SPI result: %d", res)));

    returnValues[0] = SPIReturnDatum(&isNull[0], 1);

    if (isNull[0])
        elog(WARNING, "document create failed");

    // Now try to read the inserted record back
    const char *readQuery = psprintf(
        "SELECT document FROM database.table WHERE partition_key = 7598981674407438314 "
        "AND id = '1234'");
    
    res = SPI_execute_with_args(readQuery, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, true, 1);

    if (res != SPI_OK_SELECT)
        ereport(ERROR, (errmsg("Failed to execute SELECT query: %d", res)));

    if (SPI_processed == 0)
        elog(WARNING, "document with id 1234 does not exist");

    if (SPI_finish() != SPI_OK_FINISH)
        ereport(ERROR, (errmsg("could not finish SPI connection")));

    PG_RETURN_VOID();
}


Steps I've Already Tried

Transaction and Snapshot Management:


I verified that the INSERT operation succeeds.
I checked the isolation level and it is READ COMMITTED.
I also tried calling CommandCounterIncrement() after the insert to ensure that the command counter advances, but this did not resolve the issue.
I confirmed that both the INSERT and SELECT are happening in the same transaction and are correctly wrapped between SPI_connect() and SPI_finish().


Sub-transactions:


I initially used sub-transactions with BeginInternalSubTransaction() but observed the same behavior when I switched to running everything in a single transaction.


Query Validation:


I validated that the queries are correct. The SELECT statement should target the record just inserted, but it doesn’t find it.
I attempted using both SPI_execute() and SPI_execute_with_args(), but the issue persists.


Logging and Debugging:


I’ve logged the result of SPI_processed and other SPI-related return codes. Everything looks as expected, except for the select query not finding the inserted record.


Command Counter and Read-Write Visibility:


After some research, I suspected this could be an issue with MVCC and PostgreSQL’s visibility rules, but I expected that changes made within the same transaction would be visible to subsequent commands. Even forcing CommandCounterIncrement() hasn’t resolved this.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance on why the inserted document isn’t visible to the subsequent select query. I’m particularly interested in understanding if there are any special considerations when using SPI for both insert and select in the same function, and whether there are additional transaction or snapshot settings that need to be explicitly managed in this scenario.
Is there something I might be missing in how PostgreSQL handles visibility or transaction state when executing multiple SPI operations in sequence? Any insights, recommendations, or best practices for handling such operations in C extensions would be highly valued.

I'm going to say it is due to this SPI_execute: It is generally unwise to mix read-only and read-write commands within a single function using SPI; that could result in very confusing behavior, since the read-only queries would not see the results of any database updates done by the read-write queries. The upsertQuery is using readonly=False and the readQuery readonly=True.

@AdrianKlaver Thanks a lot, this seems to have helped!
